# Copy duplicates of one list to another using linq

Tags: .net

I have two Lists of same type and Model is below:

```
public string Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public string Value {get; set;}
```

The first list - ListA is what needs to be copied over to second list - ListB where we find Id match

I have implemented a Comparer which only check for Id and then do a intersect to find duplicates.

```
    public bool Equals(Model x, Model y)
    {
        //Check whether the objects are the same object. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        return x != null && y != null && x.Id.Equals(y.Id);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Model obj)
    {
        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
        int hashProductName = obj.Id == null ? 0 : obj.Id.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the product. 
        return hashProductName;
    }
```

Now doing intersect:

```
IEnumerable<Model> duplicates = listA.Choices.Intersect(listB.Choices, new ModelComparer());
```

I was wondering is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to determine which elements are common to two sets? Are there duplicates within a list?

Comment: The only common element we want is Id (id will always be unique); As far as Id matches we are looking to overwrite the whole object. There can be a case where ListA has 3 objects and ListB has only 1. We need to find only 1 and just update that from ListA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main ways to do this. I would do `listB left join listA`. Then, you can process the joined set and return `itemFromA ?? itemFromB`. This is quite clean.

The other way is to first compute the intersection using `listA.Intersect(listB)`. The order of arguments is important so that elements from `listA` take priority (this is documented).

Then you can do `intersectionResult.Union(listB)`. Since `listB` is a superset of the intersection this returns `listB` but with elements from `intersectionResult` taking precedence.

I see this approach as inferior because it's very hard to conclude that it is correct. The join approach is easy.

The join approach also allows you to throw away your custom comparer which is a nuisance.

Comment: Is this correct ?                 listB.Choices.Join(listA.Choices, p => p.Id, m => m.Id, (a, m) =>
                new {m.Id, m.Name });

Comment: Have you tested that? This discards all items that are not common to the lists. `from b in B join a in A on ... equals ... into j let a = j.SOD() select b ?? a`. Looks like a magical incantation but it combines well understood patterns such as the left join LINQ pattern.